# Smoothing without losing data points

Tags: time-series, smoothing

How would I smooth a series of data without losing the ends of a series? For example, if I have $i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n$, and I apply a moving average, I lose the start and end of the series ($i_1$ and $i_n$, certainly, and perhaps more). I can't seem to find any smoothing method that lets me keep both ends of the series. Is this possible?

Comment: You have infinitely many choices, but one immediately presents itself: *keep the ends of the series.*  There's nothing to prevent you from doing that.  For a more sophisticated approach, read the chapters on smoothing in Tukey's book [EDA](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Exploratory_Data_Analysis/UT9dAAAAIAAJ?hl=en).

Comment: @whuber - how would I do that with a moving average type approach? I imagine $i_{2_{new}} = (i_1 + i_2 + i_3)/3$. Because we don't have an $i_0$, $i_1$ must be dropped or zero padded (which biases the data)

Comment: Don't pad with zeros: pad with the corresponding $i_j.$  E.g., for $i=(1,3,2,4)$ and a windowed mean of length 3, $\tilde i = (2,3)$ gets padded at the left with $1$ and at the right with $4$ to yield $(1,2,3,4).$  Tukey calls this "copying on." He offers other approaches with more sophistication, such as linear extrapolation at the ends.